# Prove that $^{n+r}C_r \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, limits

> How do I prove that $^{n+r}C_r \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Writing $^{n+r}C_r = \frac{(n+r)!}{n!r!}$ does not help as it is indeterminate.

I think it tends to infinity because the number of ways of choosing $r$ objects from an collection of an increasing number of objects would also increase without bound. It is quoted as part of a STEP question as an obvious statement, but I can't see an obvious proof.

Comment: $(n+r)! = n! (n+1)(n+2) \dots (n+r) \ge n! n^{r} r!$

Comment: **Hint:**
$${n+r \choose r} = \frac{(n+r)!}{n!\cdot r!} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\dots (n+r)}{r!}$$

Comment: You need $r\geq 1$ of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\binom{n+r}{r} \ge \left\lfloor \frac{n+r}{r} \right\rfloor > \frac{n}{r}$$ because $n+r$ objects contain $\lfloor \frac{n+r}{r} \rfloor$ disjoint groups of $r$ objects each, that could each be chosen. When $n \to \infty$, clearly $\frac{n}r \to \infty$.